# Can't get facebook user's email using facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook authentication on my website using javascript sdk. I can get my email and name but I can't get their email, if they're loging in, only their name (it's my fb developer app).

It asks for the login, in case no one is logged in on facebook yet but get nothing happens. If I put an alert where it's supposed to login to my app and it indeed returns the name, just not the email. But if it's me I get both. Why's that?

Here's my code:

```
<%-- Facebook conection script--%>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script> FB.init({
 appId: '334351783684824',
 cookie: true,
 xfbml: true,
 version: 'v2.8'


});

    function fbAuthUser() {
        FB.login(checkLoginStatus);;
    }

    function checkLoginStatus(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me', 'GET', { fields: 'email,name' }, function (response) {
                alert(response.email + "; " + response.name);
                Ajax(response.email, response.name);
            });
        }
    }


    function Ajax(expressao1, expressao2) {
        var request = { email: expressao1, nome: expressao2 }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'login.aspx/LoginExterno',
            method: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (resp) {
                window.location.href = resp.d;
            },
            error: function () { }
        })
    }
</script>
```

It's supposed to login and, after getting the data, use that ajax function to access a code behind c# function that redirects the user to the index, if he/she already has an account or to the registry if he/she doesn't have one. It doesn't even go in the Ajax function, because the email parameter is undefined, probably. But when both are present it does.

So, how can I get the email?

Comment: there are many threads about not getting the email for other accounts, did you read them? not all user accounts have emails.

Comment: Hi. Yea, I read a few of them and I tried them, but I still can't get it.

Comment: I've asked two people to test it and couldn't get it. And yes, they do have email on their facebook accounts. I've even asked to try to show it on their facebook profile. But still can't get it.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I posted it bellow. Simple enough, but when you're new to using facebook software it can be a little frustrating sometimes. But it was an interesting thing to solve. Thanks, anyway. :)

Comment: ok, did not even check FB.login because you wrote that it works for your own account...

Comment: Yes, it must be because I'm the app's owner. So it probably already has access to the permissions. I don't see any other reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it. On on FB.Login function, I need to add the scope and the user has to give permission. On my code, it would be like:

```
  FB.login(checkLoginStatus,{scope: 'email'});;
```